# Depuis quand « s'éteindre » signifie-t-il « mourir » etc. ?

Tags: histoire, origine-ou-raison, évolution

Le *DHLF (Rey)* dit:

> *S'éteindre*, « s'affaiblir, mourir doucement », est attesté en 1165 (Chrétien de Troyes) puis par euphémisme signifie « mourir ».
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, chez
> *Robert*, 2011 ]

Par exemple *La sénatrice Dianne Feinstein s’éteint à l’âge de 90 ans* (ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/2023-09-29/la-senatrice-dianne-feinstein-s-eteint-a-l-age-de-90-ans.php)).

Depuis quand « s'éteindre » est-il attesté comme signifiant carrément « mourir » (par euphémisme) et peut-on produire parmi les tout premiers exemples ?

---

Remarques sur *Chrétien de Troyes* :

Dans le [DÉCT](http://zeus.atilf.fr/dect/) (*Dictionnaire électronique de Chrétien de Troyes*), on trouve deux citations avec *esteindre* signifiant essentiellement « mourir » :

> A ce metez antente et cure Que feite soit an tel meniere Et la sepouture et la biere Que je n'i **muire** ne **estaingne** (Cl 5281).
> Puis se let vers terre cliner, Si se vost feire traïner A son cheval tant qu'il **estaigne**, Une ore plus vivre ne daigne. (La 4293).

Chose certaine, dans la première *muire* est une graphie de *morir* (mourir) qu'on trouve citée dans cette vedette-là (*morir*) au DÉCT... Il s'ensuit qu'on peut raisonnablement penser à tout le moins que dans cet exemple, *muire* et *estaigne* n'ont pas le même sens.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148852/discussion-on-question-by-s-h-a-r-p-r-i-f-t-depuis-quand--seteindre--signifie); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Il y en a sûrement de plus vieilles, mais voici une occurrence où *éteindre* signifie clairement *mourir* qui date de 1549 :

> [...] mais il fut tantôt éteint, ou par maladie naturelle, ou par poison [...]

[image]

Jean Lemaire de Belges, *Les illustrations de Gaule et singularitez de Troye.*

Comment: On pourrait comprendre _tantost_ comme _bien assez vite_, plutôt que _subitement_. Mais la question semble être à propos de degrés de rapidité de la mort en question - peut-être, le titre suggère un passage de _s'éteindre_ à _mourir_, mais le texte de la question un passage de _mourir doucement_ à _mourir tout court_, et je ne suis pas un spécialiste de tous les sens de _tantost_ à cette époque là. Il faudrait plus d'exemples - avec un ou deux exemples, on peut sans doute tirer le débat dans un sens ou dans l'autre.