# « S'éteindre » subitement ou suite à une (longue) maladie : proportion ?

Tags: sens, usage, fréquence-utilisation

Quand *s'[éteindre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9teindre)* est employé (par [euphémisme](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53724) ou autrement) pour signifier qu'une personne est morte (*s'est éteinte*), quelle est généralement la proportion de fois où c'est *subitement* par rapport à celles où c'est suite à une (longue) maladie ? Ceci nous permet-il d'affirmer qu'on ne peut s'éteindre « subitement » et/ou que l'emploi par euphémisme n'existe pas ? Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3):

Imagines que tu es un auteur en train d'écrire un roman, ou bien un poète. Pourquoi ne pourrais-tu pas écrire *il s'est éteint* pour suggérer ce que tu veux sur la mort de la personne - je pense que tout le monde comprendra que *s'éteindre = mourir* en général. Quand à la nuance que tu veux y mettre, tu es libre. Tu peux dire *s'éteindre subitement*, *s'éteindre lentement*, *s'éteindre doucement*, *s'éteindre brutalement*, *s'éteindre de façon imprévue*... - il n'y a pas de règle, d'interdit ou d'obligation ici. Si le contexte indique que *s'éteindre* signifie *mourir*, on peut l'agrémenter des qualifications que l'on veut et lui faire porter les nuances que l'on veut.

Pour ce qui est de l'usage courant, et sans prétendre examiner toutes les combinaisons possibles, les ngrams de Google (avec tous leurs défauts), semblent suggérer que *s'éteindre* serait plus courant dans les cas de mort "*lente*", quoique l'on trouve couramment de nombreux contre-exemples.

[image]

Par opposition à:

[image]

Ou encore:

[image]

En fait, si l'on creuse un peu dans les ngrams de Google, on a l'impression que *s'éteindre* semble être de moins en moins utilisé, au profit de *mort* tout simplement. Par exemple:

[image]

Mais encore une fois, on trouve de nombreux contre-exemples, et les conclusions basées sur les ngrams (à part la question de la qualité des ngrams de Google) vont diverger suivant les expressions, ce qui rend une véritable étude statistique difficile, mais on a une vague impression que *mort* a tendance à supplanter *s'éteindre*, probablement car le mot est plus simple (mon interprétation).